# How to build C++ protobuf?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, protocol-buffers, bazel

How to build C++ protobuf so that `g++ pb.cpp pb.pb.cc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf)` works? (`pb.cpp` provided below, `pb.pb.cc` generated from incomplete protobuf build) The compiled version must be 4.22.0 or higher.

I do not want to use `apt-get install -y protobuf-compiler libprotobuf-dev` because the versions are too old ([3.12 in `apt`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=protobuf-compiler&searchon=names&suite=kinetic&section=all), [4.22 in source](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/v4.22.0)) so I try and build them myself from source.

---

## CMake

Steps from [`cmake/README.md`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/d41deb9dc6602701b157739a314ad6405f9b89ed/cmake/README.md#linux-builds).

```bash
> cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=14
<truncated, no errors>

> cmake --build build --target install
<truncated, no errors>
Scanning dependencies of target log_internal_check_op
[ 43%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/log/CMakeFiles/log_internal_check_op.dir/internal/check_op.cc.o
[ 44%] Linking CXX shared library libabsl_log_internal_check_op.so
[ 44%] Built target log_internal_check_op
<truncated, no errors>

> g++ pb.cpp pb.pb.cc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf)
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc3B1oMq.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN4absl12lts_2023012512log_internal21CheckOpMessageBuilder7ForVar2Ev'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libabsl_log_internal_check_op.so.2301.0.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

> g++ pb.cpp pb.pb.cc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf --libs absl_log_internal_check_op)
<truncated, no errors>
```

Although the last command works fine, the additional `pkg-config --cflags --libs absl_log_internal_check_op` is not required if I use `apt-get install -y protobuf-compiler libprotobuf-dev`.

How can I build protobur *properly* so that `g++ pb.cpp pb.pb.cc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf)` without the `--libs absl_log_internal_check_op` works?

---

## Bazel

I have followed the steps exactly with no warnings at [`README.md`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/d41deb9dc6602701b157739a314ad6405f9b89ed/src/README.md#c-protobuf---unix) but still cannot use the files.

The errors:

1. Well-known types (for example, `timestamp.proto`) missing

   - In [official build (`protoc-22.0-linux-x86_64.zip`)](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v22.0/protoc-22.0-linux-x86_64.zip), part of `include/`
   - The corresponding `*.cc` and `*.h` are present at `bazel-bin/src/google/protobuf/wkt/google/protobuf` (only `*.proto` missing)
   - They are all in the [source directory](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/v22.0/src/google/protobuf) so don't know why they're removed

     - I don't want to copy from this directory directly because it contains extra files (`unittest_*`)
2. `*.pc` files not included in build (used as `pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf`)

   - [Source file](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/v22.0/cmake/protobuf.pc.cmake)

---

For convenience, here is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ARG INSTALL_LOCATION="./installed"
ENV PATH="$PATH:$INSTALL_LOCATION/bin"

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y g++ git

# Bazel install (Protobuf dependency)
# https://bazel.build/install/ubuntu#install-on-ubuntu
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https curl gnupg
RUN curl -fsSL https://bazel.build/bazel-release.pub.gpg | gpg --dearmor >bazel-archive-keyring.gpg
RUN mv bazel-archive-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings
RUN echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/bazel-archive-keyring.gpg] https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable jdk1.8" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y bazel
RUN bazel --version

# Protobuf C++ build
# https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/d41deb9dc6602701b157739a314ad6405f9b89ed/src/README.md#c-protobuf---unix
RUN git clone https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf.git
RUN cd protobuf && git submodule update --init --recursive
RUN cd protobuf && bazel build :protoc :protobuf
RUN cd protobuf && cp bazel-bin/protoc "$INSTALL_LOCATION/bin"

# Only protoc installed
# Missing:
#   protobuf.pc: pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf
#   google/protobuf/timestamp.proto: part of protoc-22.0-linux-x86_64.zip which should be included

COPY pb.proto .
# Generates pb.pb.cc and pb.pb.h
RUN protoc --cpp_out=. pb.proto

COPY pb.cpp .
# Error
# RUN g++ pb.cpp pb.pb.cc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf)
```

## `pb.proto`

```
syntax = "proto3";

package pb;

// Well-known type that ships with release distribution
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message Test {
  google.protobuf.Timestamp time = 1;
}
```

## `pb.cpp`

```
#include "pb.pb.h"

int main() {
  GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION;

  pb::Test some_var;

  /* other code here, but not required for error */
}
```

## `ldd`

### `libprotobuf-dev`

```
> ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff10b24000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f2281be8000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2281a06000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2281814000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2281f00000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f22817f9000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f22816aa000)
```

### CMake

```
> ldd /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff3098d000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5952b05000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f5952ae9000)
    libabsl_die_if_null.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_die_if_null.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952ae4000)
    libabsl_statusor.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_statusor.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952ade000)
    libabsl_log_internal_check_op.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_log_internal_check_op.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952ad5000)
    libabsl_log_internal_message.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_log_internal_message.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952ac9000)
    libabsl_log_internal_nullguard.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_log_internal_nullguard.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952ac2000)
    libabsl_hash.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_hash.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952abd000)
    libabsl_raw_hash_set.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_raw_hash_set.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952ab8000)
    libabsl_status.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_status.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952aac000)
    libabsl_cord.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_cord.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952a92000)
    libabsl_synchronization.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_synchronization.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952a82000)
    libabsl_time.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_time.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952a68000)
    libabsl_time_zone.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_time_zone.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952a48000)
    libabsl_str_format_internal.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_str_format_internal.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952a2b000)
    libabsl_bad_variant_access.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_bad_variant_access.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952a26000)
    libabsl_strings.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_strings.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952a05000)
    libabsl_throw_delegate.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_throw_delegate.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f59529fe000)
    libabsl_spinlock_wait.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_spinlock_wait.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f59529f7000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f5952815000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f59527fa000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5952608000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5952df1000)
    libabsl_raw_logging_internal.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_raw_logging_internal.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952603000)
    libabsl_examine_stack.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_examine_stack.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f59525fc000)
    libabsl_log_internal_format.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_log_internal_format.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f59525f7000)
    libabsl_log_internal_proto.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_log_internal_proto.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f59525f2000)
    libabsl_strerror.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_strerror.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f59525ed000)
    libabsl_log_internal_log_sink_set.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_log_internal_log_sink_set.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f59525e6000)
    libabsl_log_internal_globals.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_log_internal_globals.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f59525e1000)
    libabsl_log_globals.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_log_globals.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f59525d9000)
    libabsl_base.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_base.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f59525d3000)
    libabsl_city.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_city.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f59525ce000)
    libabsl_low_level_hash.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_low_level_hash.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f59525c9000)
    libabsl_cordz_info.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_cordz_info.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f59525c2000)
    libabsl_cord_internal.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_cord_internal.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f59525a7000)
    libabsl_crc_cord_state.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_crc_cord_state.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f595259f000)
    libabsl_cordz_functions.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_cordz_functions.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f595259a000)
    libabsl_stacktrace.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_stacktrace.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952595000)
    libabsl_symbolize.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_symbolize.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f595258b000)
    libabsl_malloc_internal.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_malloc_internal.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952584000)
    libabsl_int128.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_int128.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f595257a000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f595242b000)
    libabsl_strings_internal.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_strings_internal.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952425000)
    libabsl_log_sink.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_log_sink.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952420000)
    libabsl_cordz_handle.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_cordz_handle.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952418000)
    libabsl_crc32c.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_crc32c.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952412000)
    libabsl_exponential_biased.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_exponential_biased.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f595240d000)
    libabsl_debugging_internal.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_debugging_internal.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f5952406000)
    libabsl_demangle_internal.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_demangle_internal.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f59523f9000)
    libabsl_crc_internal.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_crc_internal.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007f59523f0000)

> ldd /usr/local/lib/libabsl_log_internal_check_op.so.2301.0.0
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff09986000)
    libabsl_log_internal_nullguard.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_log_internal_nullguard.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007fa936193000)
    libabsl_strings.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_strings.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007fa936172000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa935f8c000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa935f71000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa935d7f000)
    libabsl_strings_internal.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_strings_internal.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007fa935d79000)
    libabsl_throw_delegate.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_throw_delegate.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007fa935d70000)
    libabsl_raw_logging_internal.so.2301.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libabsl_raw_logging_internal.so.2301.0.0 (0x00007fa935d6b000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa935c1c000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa9361a3000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa935bf9000)
```

Comment: @kiner_shah I tried using CMake. There is still small problem (see updated post CMake section).

Comment: Please do `ldd libprotobuf.so` on the file generated through CMake and compare it with `ldd libprotobuf.so` on the file you got through libprotobuf-dev.

Comment: @kiner_shah `ldd` info added. List is longer for own build, but all libraries found.

Comment: I am not sure why does your protobuf build requires a dependency on libabseil. I will suggest removing libabseil installation from your local machine and retry.

Comment: @kiner_shah how can I do that? Abseil is [part of protobuf](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/v4.22.0/third_party). I'm not familiar with CMake, but is Abseil not linked properly in the [CMake files](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/v4.22.0/cmake)?

Comment: I had recently built protobuf static libraries for Android and that didn't require Abseil because I didn't clone the submodules (unintentionally). Maybe you can try that way and see if it builds without it. Otherwise it's a pain - https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/10431.

Comment: @kiner_shah I am able to build and use the older protobuf versions (3.21 and older), but I require 4.22 or newer. 4.22 without cloning submodules does not work. Abseil was added to 4.22 on January 25, 2023 (less than a month ago).

Comment: I recommend raising issues on their repo itself and ask their developers to resolve that. Also, is there any specific reason you want latest version? I was able to compile v3.21.12 for Android without any dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with linking. My error message was similar:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/veda-sdr-monitor.dir/gui/channels/channels_receiver.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN4absl12lts_2023080212log_internal17MakeCheckOpStringIllEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEET_T0_PKc'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libabsl_log_internal_check_op.so.2308.0.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

The reason is that the script `Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake` provided by `CMake` which is initiated by the `CMake` command

```
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
```

is incompatible with `protobuf` versions 22+ (up to 24.3) and cannot link `protobuf` library correctly. In order to solve the problem you need to use command

```
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED CONFIG)
```

This will enforce `cmake` to use the script `/usr/lib/cmake/protobuf/protobuf-config.cmake` provided by `protobuf` library.

It may happen that after this change you see a `CMake` error

```
Unknown CMake command "protobuf_generate_cpp"
```

(this is possible for new versions of `CMake`, where `protobuf_generate_cpp` has been marked as a legacy command). In this case the actions depend on whether you compile from a command line or from `QtCreator`.

If you are using command line, then call `cmake` with an additional variable

```
cmake -Dprotobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE:BOOL=ON ..
```

And if you are using `QtCreator`, then go to

```
Build Settings -> CMake -> tab "Initial configuration"
```

press **Add** button and choose **Boolean**. Replace **<UNSET>** by **protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE** and check the box, so that it shows **ON**. Then press **Re-configure with initial parameters**.

The solution was found [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/12746)